# Creating "ALL" option using fetchxml

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, fetchxml

I need to create a report which prompts the user to select from category parameter and I would like to display the ALL option in the drop down menu parameter. Previously, I have used SQL server to create my dataset, but now I am using fetchxml. I would like to know if there is a way to create a drop down parameter with an option "ALL" to choose all the choices in the parameter.

I have already created a new dataset to generate my parameter, but I dont know how to add "ALL" Option.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42776385/allow-a-select-all-option-in-dynamic-crm-report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Report go to your Parameter, Select Multiple Value Check box.
When you preview your report it will show you an option ALL in your drop down list.

Now in your Fetchxml query you could use IN operator to fetch data for all parameter values.

Comment: yeah, I used the built in function